# LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.utf-8)

Tags: arch-linux, configuration, locale

I know this question has been asked before but none of the answers worked out for me.

I use Arch Linux and KDE with the linux-zen kernel and I have set my locale to `en_US.utf-8`.

Whenever I open Konsole I get:

```
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.utf-8)
```

How can I fix this?

Here is my `/etc/environment`:

```
#
# This file is parsed by pam_env module
#
# Syntax: simple "KEY=VAL" pairs on separate lines
#

LANG=en_US.utf-8
LC_ALL=C
```

I have also set `LC_ALL` to `C` in my `.bashrc`.

Comment: If you are using Arch (and not a derivative distribution, which wouldn't be guaranteed to be configured the same way), don't forget the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Locale), which is IMO quite clear on how to deal with locales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file ***/etc/enviroment*** has nothing to do with system locale and you have to edit `LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8`. `LC_ALL=C` was back in the days but you using a rolling release.

**When using `sysvinit` or `openrc` or something similar ...**

your locales are created with `locale-gen` and ***/etc/locale.gen*** then passed to ***/etc/locale.conf*** and ***/etc/env.d/02locale***

Here is an example ...

```
[~] cat /etc/locale.gen 

C.UTF8 UTF-8
en_US ISO-8859-1
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
de_DE ISO-8859-1
de_DE@euro ISO-8859-15
de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8

[~] cat /etc/locale.conf 
# Configuration file for eselect
LANG="de_DE.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"

[~] cat /etc/env.d/02locale 
# Configuration file for eselect
LANG="de_DE.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"

[~] ls -l /etc/env.d/02locale 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14  1. Aug 20:10 /etc/env.d/02locale -> ../locale.conf
```

Verify that the selected locales are available by running `locale -a` and after availability is verified you can run `source /etc/profile` to update your system on the fly.

Note: locale will be saved to ***/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive*** and can be checked via `localedef --list-archive`.

**When using `systemd` ...**

1. Get a list of available locales with `localectl list-locales`.
2. Set the desired locale via `localectl set-locale LANG=de_DE.utf8` and `localectl set-locale LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8` if needed.
3. Check result with `localectl`.

Comment: `env-update` seems to be a Gentoo-specific script and is not used in Arch Linux.

Comment: oops, thx for the advice. I edited my post.

Comment: For some reason, it just went away but I'm sure this would work too!